# Para cada valor de uma tabela mostrar o corresponde, caso não tenha mostrar zero

Tags: sql, join

O que eu quero fazer é o seguinte:

Mostrar para cada linha da tabela vendedores o número de passes vendidos, mas caso não tenha vendido nenhum passe mostrar 0.
Tem uma query anterior no sistema que faz parecido, mas só mostra os vendedores que tem ingresso vendido, mas eu queria mostrar caso não tivesse ingresso vendido aparecer 0.

```
SELECT
/**#Campos buscados**/

    vendedores.id,
    vendedores.nome,
    vendedores.email,
    vendedores.telefone,
    vendedores.rg,
    vendedores.created_at,
    count(passes.id) passes
/**#Essa parte é só pra somar o Valor de vendas (taxas e preço)**/
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(format(SUM(preco * (CASE
                                              WHEN modalidade_id IS NOT NULL THEN 100 - desconto
                                              ELSE 100
                                          END) / 100 + taxa * (CASE
                                                                  WHEN modalidade_id IS NOT NULL THEN 100 - taxes_discounts
                                                                  ELSE 100
                                                              END) / 100), 2), '.','@'),',','.'),'@',',') as Valor_Vendas

/**#Inner joins**/
FROM vendedores
    INNER JOIN embaixador_passes ON vendedores.id = embaixador_passes.embaixador_id
    INNER JOIN passes ON passes.id = embaixador_passes.ingresso_id
    INNER JOIN eventos ON passes.evento_id = eventos.id
    INNER JOIN pedidos ON pedidos.id = embaixador_passes.pedido_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pedido_statuses ON pedido_statuses.id = pedidos.pedido_status_id
    LEFT JOIN modalidades ON modalidades.id = embaixador_passes.modalidade_id
WHERE pedido_statuses.id IN (5 , 8)
    AND passes.evento_id = 40;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua:

```
FROM
                  vendedores
                      INNER JOIN
```

por:

```
FROM
                  vendedores
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN
```

Answer (score 2):

Para trazer vendidos e não vendidos, você precisa mudar o `INNER JOIN` para `RIGHT JOIN`, para trazer registros do "lado direto" mesmo que não já registros correspondente do "outro lado":

```
RIGHT JOIN passes ON passes.id = embaixador_passes.ingresso_id
```

E para mostrar zero no lugar de nulos, use a função `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(count(passes.id), 0 ) passes
```

Comment: Eu queria trazer todos os vendedores, mas mesmo trocando o join não deu certo.
O isNull também não deu certo, sempre mostra zero.

Comment: Seria mais fácil te ajudar se tivesse uma amostra de dados.. não consegue montar a estrutura das tabelas com alguns dados aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

O único jeito de validar se existem dados na tabela de *Passes* é utilizar o **LEFT JOIN** ao invés do **INNER JOIN**.